# How to get column names of two tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am currently using following query to fetch column name from a single mysql table

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME as column_name 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'product' 
            AND COLUMN_NAME 
                NOT IN ('ean','jan','isbn','mpn','upc');
```

How can i fetch the column name from multiple tables? Is there any options like JOIN for this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME as column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'product' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('ean','jan','isbn','mpn','upc'))
   OR (TABLE_NAME = 'other_table' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('something_else'))
```

Comment: It works fine ! I just want a tip if there is some similar name of columns what will be the result ? How can an aliasing will done by mysql in case it will show result any how ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Suppose i have two table one is order table other is order_product table. both table have order_id columns. then how mysql will display it on query. or what will be the aliasing strategy it will use.

Comment: it will output 2 records, meaning 2 rows with the same content: `order_id`. If you want the table name being displayed too, then add `TABLE_NAME` to the `select`. Just run the query and you will see

Answer (score 0):

Use below query

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME as column_name 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME in ('product' , 'other table name')
            AND COLUMN_NAME 
                NOT IN ('ean','jan','isbn','mpn','upc');
```